# Modifying font size of "addImageQuery" popup in Leaflet in R

Tags: css, leaflet

I am struggling to figure out how to change the size of the popup (font size) produced by the "addImageQuery" function from the "leafem" package. In other words, I want the popup that displays "Layer poppendorf: 9048" (upper right-hand corner) in the attached picture to be larger so the text is more legible. The major issue is that the function apparently has no class name, so I don't know what class to reference in "tags$style". I tried defining the class name within the function, but that didn't work, as shown below.

[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XBDQ.png)

```
library(leaflet)
library(plainview)
library(htmltools)
library(leafem)

map <- leaflet() %>%
addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
addRasterImage(poppendorf[[1]], project = TRUE, group = "poppendorf", layerId = "poppendorf") %>%
addImageQuery(poppendorf[[1]], project = TRUE, layerId = "poppendorf", className = "query") %>%
addLayersControl(overlayGroups = "poppendorf")

browsable(tagList(list(
tags$head(
  tags$style(".leaflet .query i{border-radius: 50%;width:18px;height: 18px;margin-top: 4px;}")),
map)))
```